# Google Sheets stripping single quotes from the beginning of string cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting, array-formulas

I am using the IMPORTDATA function to get info from a MySQL database (via PHP script) into a Google spreadsheet. One of the fields consists of a string formatted number that needs to be stored as follows:

```
'982000405532718
```

The text output generated by the PHP script provides data for this column using double quotes to indicate it to be stored as string:

```
"'982000405532718"
```

For some reason the IMPORTDATA function also strips the single-quote so that only

```
982000405532718
```

shows up in the spreadsheet.

Is there a way to tell Google Sheets to leave the single-quote?

Comment: Please respond to the previous comment, to make your shared sheet accessible.  Or perhaps delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

try to force it like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT(IMPORTDATA("url-here")))
```

Comment: Nopes. That messes up the rest of the columns (e.g. dates) and still strips the single quote from the string...

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iHg-7FqaA77aub8UbZvDo8UkKbbugEcfe6eZst8eQ_Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iHg-7FqaA77aub8UbZvDo8UkKbbugEcfe6eZst8eQ_Y/edit?usp=sharing